# HTML email button alignment in Outlook

Tags: outlook, zurb-foundation, html-email, inky

I'm having some issues aligning the call to action buttons in a HTML email I am building for a client. The buttons are appearing off to the left and not filled correctly.

This is how they appear in my browser and most email clients:

[image: Correct buttons]

And this is how they appear in Outlook 2016:

[image: Outlook output]

Here is my Inky markup:

```html
<row class="call-to-actions">
    <columns small="6">
        <spacer size="50"></spacer>
        <button class="facebook float-right" href="#">Like on Facebook</button>
        <spacer size="50"></spacer>
    </columns>
    <columns small="6">
        <spacer size="50"></spacer>
        <button class="twitter" href="#">Follow on Twitter</button>
        <spacer size="50"></spacer>
    </columns>
</row>
```

My SASS for the buttons:

```css
table {
  &.button {
    table {
      td {
        background: transparent !important;
      }
    }
    &.facebook {
      table {
        background-color: #3b5998;
        td {
          a {
            background-color: #3b5998;
            border: none;
            line-height: 30px;
          }
        }
      }
    }

    &.twitter {
      table {
        background-color: #1da1f2;
        td {
          background-color: #1da1f2;
          a {
            background-color: #1da1f2;
            border: none;
            line-height: 30px;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am using Foundation for Email to compile the mark up into email friendly HTML. This is how it is the generated output:

```html
<table class="row call-to-actions" style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;display:table;padding:0;position:relative;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;width:100%">

  <tbody>
    <tr style="padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top">
      <th class="small-6 large-6 columns first"
      style="Margin:0 auto;color:#878787;font-family:&#39;Circular Book&#39;,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:400;line-height:1.6;margin:0 auto;padding:0;padding-bottom:0!important;padding-left:16px;padding-right:10px!important;text-align:left;width:274px">

        <table style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;width:100%">
          <tbody>
            <tr style="padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top">
              <th style="Margin:0;color:#878787;font-family:&#39;Circular Book&#39;,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:400;line-height:1.6;margin:0;padding:0;text-align:left">

                <table class="spacer"
                style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;width:100%">
                  <tbody>
                    <tr style="padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top">
                      <td style="-moz-hyphens:auto;-webkit-hyphens:auto;Margin:0;border-collapse:collapse!important;color:#878787;font-family:&#39;Circular Book&#39;,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:50px;font-weight:400;hyphens:auto;line-height:50px;margin:0;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word"
                      height="50px"></td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
                <table class="button facebook float-right"
                style="Margin:0;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;float:right;margin:0;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;width:auto">

                  <tbody>
                    <tr style="padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top">
                      <td style="-moz-hyphens:auto;-webkit-hyphens:auto;Margin:0;border-collapse:collapse!important;color:#878787;font-family:&#39;Circular Book&#39;,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:400;hyphens:auto;line-height:1.6;margin:0;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word">

                        <table style="background-color:#3b5998;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;width:100%">

                          <tbody>
                            <tr style="padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top">
                              <td style="-moz-hyphens:auto;-webkit-hyphens:auto;Margin:0;background:0 0!important;border:none;border-collapse:collapse!important;color:#fff;font-family:&#39;Circular Book&#39;,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:400;hyphens:auto;line-height:1.6;margin:0;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word">

                                <a href="#"
                                style="Margin:0;background-color:#3b5998;border:none;border-radius:500px;color:#fff;display:inline-block;font-family:&#39;Circular Book&#39;,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:400;line-height:30px;margin:0;padding:8px 16px 8px 16px;text-align:left;text-decoration:none">
                                Like on Facebook</a>
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                          </tbody>
                        </table>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
                <table class="spacer"
                style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;width:100%">
                  <tbody>
                    <tr style="padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top">
                      <td style="-moz-hyphens:auto;-webkit-hyphens:auto;Margin:0;border-collapse:collapse!important;color:#878787;font-family:&#39;Circular Book&#39;,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:50px;font-weight:400;hyphens:auto;line-height:50px;margin:0;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word"
                      height="50px"></td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </th>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </th>
      <th class="small-6 large-6 columns last"
      style="Margin:0 auto;color:#878787;font-family:&#39;Circular Book&#39;,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:400;line-height:1.6;margin:0 auto;padding:0;padding-bottom:0!important;padding-left:10px!important;padding-right:16px;text-align:left;width:274px">

        <table style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;width:100%">
          <tbody>
            <tr style="padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top">
              <th style="Margin:0;color:#878787;font-family:&#39;Circular Book&#39;,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:400;line-height:1.6;margin:0;padding:0;text-align:left">

                <table class="spacer"
                style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;width:100%">
                  <tbody>
                    <tr style="padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top">
                      <td style="-moz-hyphens:auto;-webkit-hyphens:auto;Margin:0;border-collapse:collapse!important;color:#878787;font-family:&#39;Circular Book&#39;,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:50px;font-weight:400;hyphens:auto;line-height:50px;margin:0;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word" height="50px"></td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
                <table class="button twitter"
                style="Margin:0;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;margin:0;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;width:auto">

                  <tbody>
                    <tr style="padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top">
                      <td style="-moz-hyphens:auto;-webkit-hyphens:auto;Margin:0;border-collapse:collapse!important;color:#878787;font-family:&#39;Circular Book&#39;,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:400;hyphens:auto;line-height:1.6;margin:0;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word">

                        <table style="background-color:#1da1f2;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;width:100%">

                          <tbody>
                            <tr style="padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top">
                              <td style="-moz-hyphens:auto;-webkit-hyphens:auto;Margin:0;background:0 0!important;background-color:#1da1f2;border:none;border-collapse:collapse!important;color:#fff;font-family:&#39;Circular Book&#39;,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:400;hyphens:auto;line-height:1.6;margin:0;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word">

                                <a href="#"
                                style="Margin:0;background-color:#1da1f2;border:none;border-radius:500px;color:#fff;display:inline-block;font-family:&#39;Circular Book&#39;,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:400;line-height:30px;margin:0;padding:8px 16px 8px 16px;text-align:left;text-decoration:none">
                                Follow on Twitter</a>
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                          </tbody>
                        </table>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
                <table class="spacer"
                style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;width:100%">
                  <tbody>
                    <tr style="padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top">
                      <td style="-moz-hyphens:auto;-webkit-hyphens:auto;Margin:0;border-collapse:collapse!important;color:#878787;font-family:&#39;Circular Book&#39;,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:50px;font-weight:400;hyphens:auto;line-height:50px;margin:0;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word" height="50px"></td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </th>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I put an upvote on your question because you sent detailed examples so I could look at your code, determine some issues and offer suggestions and a fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`padding` support is buggy with Outlook 2007-2016. It does not work at all with Notes.

- https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/box-model/padding/

`line-height` is also buggy with Outlook.

- https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/text-fonts/line-height/

I might try setting the `<td height="30">` to the parent of your href so that you get your height for the button, "Like on Facebook".

In addition, `font-family:&#39;Circular Book&#39;` is not going to work with Outlook. Web font support is buggy as well. Some fonts work, but fonts with two names that are not web safe causes Outlook to revert to it's web-safe font, Times New Roman.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I'll test them later today.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very common problem in Outlook. I recommend [Bulletproof Buttons by Campaign Monitor](http://buttons.cm). It is very nice cross platform and works super awesome.

Comment: Sadly Bulletproof Buttons aren't available natively in the framework we use (Foundation for emails).